# Embedded SVG into Inkscape

Tags: svg, inkscape, gliffy

I have a SVG file (an exported Gliffy diagram) that I want to open and edit in Inkscape. When viewing the code of the file using the developer options of Chrome, it looks like:

```
<svg xmlns="...>
  <g transform="...>
    <image xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml,%0A%20...></image>
  </g>
  ... (about 20 more <g>...</g> tags)
</svg>
```

When decoding the part starting with %0A%20..., it translates to something like

```
data:image/svg xml,
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="50000" width="50000">
            <style>
                .gliffy-rte-text {
                  ...
```

The issue is, that in Inkscape those parts will be replaced by a placeholder telling me "**Linked image not found**" and as speculated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67751776/how-to-get-a-standard-svg-file-from-svg-data-url-that-begins-with-dataimage-sv), Inkscape most likely is not able to read the CSS styling correctly or probably at all.

I would very much appreciate any thoughts or ideas on how to convert the file such that it can be edited and displayed correctly in Inkscape.

Comment: Presumably, you'll need to edit the extract the styles from the .css and edit the .svg accordingly to match

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I am assuming that you are referring to something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930212/how-to-import-svg-code-into-inkscape using the XML Editor in Inkscape? I was hoping to get around that, because I assume to have a lot of styles to copy manually. Another way that almost gets me there is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804171/how-to-extract-svg-as-file-from-web-page#:~:text=Here%27s%20a%20three,the%20vector%20element.

Answer (score 1):

Open the wrapper file in a browser. Right-click on the area containing the embedded SVG, and choose "Save (image) as...". If the wrapper contains multiple `<image>` tags, you will have to save them to separate files, but at least they will be in a form Inkscape can handle.

If you want to get them all together in one SVG file again, you will have to re-import them via the Inkscape import function. Take care to select 'Include as editable object', or you will end up right where you started:

[image]

The speculations above about CSS are unsubstantiated, btw. Inkscape will convert the content of a `<style>` element into inline `style` attributes, but otherwise handle them correctly. What happened is stated quite clearly in the above screenshot: data URLs embeded via an `<image>` tag will not be editable in Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

You might convert all styling to element attributes using **SVGOMG**:

1. replace your embedded `<image>` element by the decoded data url content. Your parent svg should look something like this:

   ```
    <!-- parent svg -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
        <!-- embedded svg decoded data url -->
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="50000" width="50000">
        <style>
            .gliffy-rte-text {
             }
        </style>
        </svg>
    </svg>
   ```
2. Use [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) "inline styles" and "style to attribute"parameter:

[image: SVGOMG]

You should disable all other optimizing parameter, since they might strip to many other attributes.

**Expected before result**

```
    <svg viewBox="0 0 256 256" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <style>
        circle{
            fill:none;
            stroke: orange;
            stroke-width:10;
          }
        </style>
        <circle cx="128" cy="128" r="100"/>
    </svg>
```

**After**

```
    <svg viewBox="0 0 256 256" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="128" cy="128" r="100" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="10"/>   
    </svg>
```