# How to download icons from a webpage through inspect?

Tags: image, download, inspect

I am trying to recreate the youtube home page for which i am able to download the thumbnails and profile pics thorugh inspect, however the same doesnt work for downloading icons  like home,library,subscriptions, shorts etc..which are on the left menu bar thorugh inspect as i couldnt find the image source..

Is there some youtube library kind of thing from which we can download all these icons?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804171/how-to-extract-svg-as-file-from-web-page